# List of Func delegates with varying return types and number of parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a class that will require a varying number of Func delegates to be passed in the contructor. Each of these delegates will point to a different function, each with a different return type, and with a varying number of parameters (of type double). Each of these functions will then be called accordingly.

Question 1. Right now, to make things easier for those using this class, I am thinking about allowing the user to pass a `List<object>` of Func delegates. Is this possible, and if so am I able to determine the return type and number of params required for each Func in the method in which the `List<object>` is passed to (i.e. the constructor) ?

Question 2. If the above is not feasible, will I need to overload the constructor with every different combination of return types/number of params and route each Func accordingly -_- ... if not can someone point me in the right direction, I feel like i'm approaching this in the wrong way ...

note - coming from a python background, I would do something like this (i'm inexperienced in c#):

```
import inspect
def test(x): return x
inspect.getargspec(test)

returns: ArgSpec(args=['x'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your design of passing lots of funcs to a class is unusual. Have you considered defining a class with one virtual method for each func that you'd like to pass and let users override these?

Comment: You: _am I able to determine the return type and number of params required for each Func_ Instead of using `List<object>`, you can use `List<Delegate>` since all `Func` types derive from `System.Delegate`. Then if `d` is an element of the `List<Delegate>`, you can use `d.Method.ReturnType` and `d.Method.GetParameters()` to get the information you ask for. You might invoke the delegate with `d.DynamicInvoke`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Question 1. Right now, to make things easier for those using this class, I am thinking about allowing the user to pass a List of Func delegates. Is this possible, and if so am I able to determine the return type and number of params required for each Func in the method in which the List is passed to (i.e. the constructor) ?

Not really. You could allow a `List<Delegate>` (or some other collection with an element type of `Delegate`), but nothing `Func`-specific, for two reasons:

- `Func` is effectively a *family* of types, with different number of generic type parameters. These types are entirely separate as far as the CLR is concerned; `Func<TResult>` and `Func<T, TResult>` are as different as `Action<T>` and `EventHandler`.
- Even if you were only dealing with several values of the same generic type of delegate, the fact that they could have different type arguments means they're different types to the CLR; there's no way of saying `List<Func<>>` for "a list of functions with potentially varying type arguments". Again, the CLR treats them as separate types - although this time at least one with a common generic type definition.

> Question 2. If the above is not feasible, will I need to overload the constructor with every different combination of return types/number of params and route each Func accordingly

Well, there are several options:

- Make all the parameters optional, giving each of them a default value of `null`, then use named arguments when calling the constructor:

  ```
   var foo = new Foo(clickHandler: () => ...,
                     keyHandler: key => ...);
  ```
- Create a builder, so that the various functions can be set as properties - this works very well with the object initializer syntax:

  ```
   var foo = new Foo.Builder {
                 ClickHandler = () => ...,
                 KeyHandler = () => ...
             }.Build();
  ```

Both of the latter solutions depends on you really having a specific named purpose, of course.

It would help if you could be clearer about what you're trying to achieve - as dtb says, polymorphism *may* be a better fit here. You could create an abstract class with no-op implementations of virtual methods, and implementations could choose which ones to override.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I think I will go down the route of making the parameters optional. Just to be clear - could I box the delegates into a List of objects and then pass to the constructor ? If i could do this, is there a similar functionality in c# to the python inspect.getargspec method ? Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @Sherlock: There wouldn't be any boxing involved; delegates are reference types already. You could convert them all to `Delegate`, but it would probably be messy. I suspect you're still thinking too much about what you would do in Python - idiomatic C# is often very different, and the neatest solution to any given problem may well be quite different in C# to the neatest solution to the same problem in Python.